# Minesweeper check the neighbors of mines

Tags: javascript, arrays, minesweeper

I am working on 'Minesweeper' now,I have the field set up.

I have couple question. First, the number of mines should be from 1 to fieldSize-1, I am not sure if I got this correct, I declare it as 'minesNum'.
Second, assuming the number of mines are correct, then I want to check the neighbors of mines, so I have 9 if statements, but I got error message on the second if statement, which is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined'.

I am struggling with it about five hours, and I still cannot figure it out. Can anyone help me with it?
Thank you!

```
var arr=new Array(30,40);
var min=1;
var max= rows * columns;
minesNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);

for(var i=0; i<rows;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<columns;j++){
        arr[i][j]=0;
    }
}

for (var i=0; i<=minesNum; i++){
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows);
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*columns);
    if(arr[x][y]==-1){
        i--;
        continue;
    }           
    arr[x][y]=-1;
}

for(var i=0;i<rows;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<columns;j++){
        if(arr[i][j]==-1){    //mine
            continue;
        }


        if(this.arr[i-1][j]==-1){  
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }

        if(arr[i][j-1]==-1){   
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
        if(arr[i+1][j]==-1){
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
        if(arr[i][j+1]==-1){   
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
        if(arr[i+1][j+1]==-1){   
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
        if(arr[i-1][j-1]==-1){   
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
        if(arr[i-1][j+1]==-1){   
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
        if(arr[i+1][j-1]==-1){   
            arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are creating 2d array in wrong way:

```
var arr=new Array(30,40);
var min=1;
var max= rows * columns;
minesNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);

for(var i=0; i<rows;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<columns;j++){
        arr[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

this should be in :

```
var arr=new Array();
var min=1;
var max= rows * columns;
minesNum=Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min);

for(var i=0; i<rows;i++){
    arr[i]=new Array()
    for(var j=0;j<columns;j++){
        arr[i][j]=0;
    }
}
```

then change your logic based on the valid array indices

Comment: the max size of my field is 40*30, I think I should declare the array size too,right?

Comment: no need to do so. new Array(30,40) will create array with elements 30 and 40

Answer (score 0):

Answering to second part of your question, you need to first verify whether the position you are checking in if statements is valid or not.
So, before accessing arr[i-1][j], you need to first verify that (i-1) is not less than zero. If it is less than zero, it means that you are trying to access invalid position which will give you error. You need to do this in every if statement and first verify that the position you are trying to access and check is valid.

Hence, your code for if statements would become like this -

```
    if((i-1) >=0 && this.arr[i-1][j].holds==-1){  
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }

    if(j-1 >=0 && arr[i][j-1]==-1){   
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
    if(i+1 < rows && arr[i+1][j]==-1){
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
    if(j+1 <= columns && arr[i][j+1]==-1){   
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
    if(i+1 < rows && j+1 < columns && arr[i+1][j+1]==-1){   
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
    if(i-1 >= 0 && j-1 >= 0 && arr[i-1][j-1]==-1){   
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
    if(i-1 >=0 && j+1 < rows && arr[i-1][j+1]==-1){   
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
    if(i+1 < rows && j-1 >=0 && arr[i+1][j-1]==-1){   
        arr[i][j]=arr[i][j]+1;
    }
```